# How to add\install to maven dependency of newly created\third party jar in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, jar, pom.xml

For a maven project a Jar file needed for my code but which is not in maven repository so, I have downloaded and added the jar file in configured remote repository.

I want to add dependency of the jar. so i would like to know

```
<groupId>?</groupId>
<artifactId>?</artifactId>
<version>?</version>
```

Also i like to know where i can find these details in the jar

Comment: you have to mention the groupId, aritfactId and version of the jar, which you gave while installing the jar file in your local repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install this JAR into your own repository, see this official [tutorial](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html).

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=jar
```

Now include this installed artifact into your project as a regular dependency.

Comment: i tried the same for FexXB.swc flex component file.
I ran as
    mvn install:install-file -Dfile=FlexXB.swc -DgroupId=com.google.code.flex -DartifactId=FlexXB -Dversion=2.3.1 -Dpackaging=swc
dependecy is created in maven local repository but there is no pom file created. so that again i'm getting error